# What's the correct configuration of main in angular-cli.json to use express?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I'm trying to configure a express server using Angular 2, in many configuration examples I saw the angular-cli.json being changed in the main configuration pointing to a server.js file.

But when I change it, the application doesn't start on ng serve.

I would have to call the main.ts file inside of the server.js? How?

Ex:

```
"main": "main.ts"
"main": "server.ts"
```

My express server is very simple, I used as base the following: https://tableless.com.br/criando-uma-aplicacao-de-chat-simples-com-nodejs-e-socket-io/

Comment: Do you need server-side rendering?  Otherwise your express side is just an endpoint and your dist/index.html will be the only file you would reference as base url.  For local proxy to your express you will set a proxy that you can find on the cli page.

Comment: No, I don't need any server-side rendering. But how I set this proxy in the cli page?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy is the proxy setup for cli.

Comment: Did you [check this page](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-angular2-express-example/blob/master/angular-cli.json)

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate from above, you are just going to build your project using the proxy for local development following the - [cli proxy docs](http://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy).

If you do something like

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

with your *proxy.conf.json*

```
{
  "/api": {
  "target": "http://localhost:3000",
  "secure": false
  }
}
```

For express as your server you will send a route back to the dist/index file with something like -

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile( DIST +'/index.html');
});
```